# Convert date format python

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I have django form and I am receiving from POST a date formated like "%d/%m/%Y" and I would like to convert it to "%Y-%m-%d", How could I do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [strptime and strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: datetime.datetime.strptime('10/05/2012', '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Out[2]: '2012-05-10'
```

Likewise, in Django template syntax you can use the [date filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date):

```
{{ mydate|date:"Y-m-d" }}
```

to print your date in your preferred format.

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use `strptime` and `strftime`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('5/10/1955', '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'1955-10-05'
```

Comment: Does this actually work for you though? You're not trying to do this in django's template language are you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [easy_date](https://github.com/ralphavalon/easy_date) to make it easy:

```
import date_converter
my_datetime = date_converter.string_to_string('02/05/2012', '%d/%m/%Y', '%Y-%m-%d')
```