# data format value changes in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

forms.py

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMAT = (
    ('%d/%m/%Y','%m/%d/%Y')
)

class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    manual_date = forms.DateField(input_formats = DATE_INPUT_FORMAT,
                      widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

1.Date format should change depend upon the value in database,if value is in db,it shows the 1st format and for none ,else part is executing.

2.Formats are changing depends upon the condition.

3.I am facing problem here,if the input format is of this (%m/%d/%Y),on form post the value of date gets interchange and saved in database.If the given date is 07/06/2013 -->7th june 2013,after form post it is viewed in the field as 06/07/2013 -->6th july 2013.It is not working properly.

Need help to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: what is `dateformat` ?

Comment: i mean what is the localvariable `dateformat` in the view ?

Comment: Its a queried value from 1 table,it holds either 1 or 0.If value is 0,the format would be dd/mm/yy and for value 1 the format would be mm/dd/yy

Comment: ok.. should this format `dateFormat: ('dd/mm/yy')` not change?

Comment: no,it is not changing

Comment: so that is the issue. You need to convert that to a format you want to store it as

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31804/discussion-between-user2086641-and-karthikr)

Comment: Can any one tell me how to convert the date in same format and save in database

Comment: what is the format you get it in the POST? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541640/convert-date-format-python

Comment: for fromat mm/dd/yy the given input is 03/07/2013 in console i got as like this 2013-07-03

Comment: Did you override your `DATE_FORMAT` ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format

Comment: Yes,date input format,i changed as you said looks like this DATE_INPUT_FORMAT = ('%d/%m/%Y','%m/%d/%Y')

Comment: manual_date field is not getting validated and data are still save in different format

Comment: No. i was talking about settings.DATE_FORMAT check the link

Comment: No,in settings input format is not updated because in form i defined the two input format and using that

Comment: If you are using two formats : dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy and if your input date is 05/07/2013 then your date matches both the format. So Django will pick the first one in your DATE_INPUT_FORMAT tuple and use that. So you will end up with D=05 and M=07 in the db.

Comment: @maulik13,so how to resolve this,what i thought was saving both input format in same format in db,so while form submit that didn't happen.

Comment: You cannot automatically detect those two formats, since you explicitly have to know in cases like 05/07/2013 where the date is and where the month is. So you should use only one of these two formats in the user form.

Comment: In application,i am in the line where i should provide both format,because my app consist of two part,1 is the report creation page and other is settings page.So settings page have the option to select the date format.Can you tell me how to save both format in same format like this 2013-05-07 in database,my problem is while post,the date and month gets interchange and save.

Comment: I think you need to inherit `DateField` and override its `strptime(...)` method to use whichever format is set by your settings. Also you should check out for your widget as it only renders `d/m/Y` format

Comment: Lot of suggestions are given from different answers but nothing completely worked for me,can i get any solution which solve all issue,because some are solving the requested issue but fail to implement fully so that to make it works perfectly.

Comment: Here i am explaining the problem once again.While giving input in (dd/mm/yyyy) format no problem but in (mm/dd/yyyy) format,in database, format gets interchange and save. /eg.If the input is (05/07/2013 in format mm/dd/yyyy) in database it save as (07/05/2013)date and month gets interchange.So kindly tell me how to solve to accept both input formats and after form post the date should not interchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another way to change the input format dynamically

**forms.py:**

```
class ReportForm(forms.Form):

    manual_time = forms.TimeField(input_formats = TIME_INPUT_FORMAT,
                      widget=forms.TimeInput(attrs={'size':'8','class':'time_field'}))
    manual_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(
                            attrs={'size':'15', 'id':'datepicker'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get the date_format if present in parameters
        date_format = None
        if 'date_format' in kwargs:
            date_format = kwargs.pop('date_format')

        super(ReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Dynamically set input date format
        if date_format:
            self.fields['manual_date'].input_formats = (date_format, )
```

**views.py**

```
def when(request):
    """To view and save report time and date
    """

    if not 'report_id' in request.session:
        return redirect('incident.views.new_report')
    report_id = request.session['report_id']
    report = Report.objects.get(pk=report_id)
    try:
        settings = Settings.objects.get(user=request.user)
        dateformat = settings.date_format
        timeformat = settings.time_format
    except:
        dateformat = False
        timeformat = False
    date = None
    time = None
    if not report.manual_date:
        report.manual_date = datetime.datetime.now()

    if not report.manual_time:
        report.manual_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    manual_date = datetime.datetime.now()

    if int(dateformat):
        date_format = '%m/%d/%Y'    
        datelabel = "Date(mm/dd/yyyy)"
        createddate = report.created_date_time.strftime('%b %d %Y')
    else:
        date_format = '%d/%m/%Y'
        datelabel = "Date(dd/mm/yyyy)"
        createddate = report.created_date_time.strftime('%d %b %Y')

    date = report.manual_date.strftime(date_format)

    if int(timeformat):
        time = report.manual_time.strftime('%H:%M')
        timelabel = "Time(24hour)"
        createdtime = report.created_date_time.strftime('%H:%M')
    else:
        time = report.manual_time.strftime('%I:%M %p')
        timelabel = "Time(12hour)"
        createdtime = report.created_date_time.strftime('%I:%M %p')

    if request.method == 'POST':

        reportform = ReportForm(request.POST, date_format=date_format)
        if reportform.is_valid():
            report.manual_date = reportform.cleaned_data['manual_data']
            report.manual_time = reportform.cleaned_data['manual_time']
            report.user = request.user
            report.save()

            if not 'next' in request.POST:
                return redirect('incident.views.report_confirm')
            return redirect('incident.views.media')
    else:    
        reportform = ReportForm(instance=report, initial={'manual_date':date, 'manual_time':time})

    leftbar = common_leftbar(request, report_id)
    return render_to_response('incident/when.html',
                               {
                                'newreport_menu': True,
                                'when_tab': True,
                                'reportform': reportform,
                                'datelabel':datelabel,
                                'timelabel':timelabel,
                                'createddate':createddate,
                                'createdtime':createdtime,
                                'incident': report,
                                'leftbar':leftbar
                                 },
                                   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The key here to change the `input_formats` attribute of DateField dynamically when you create the form. So when you submit the form, you should pass the `date_format` and the default DateField should convert your date fine. You will have to adapt this code into yours as I have assumed some of things in the code above.

Comment: You need to adapt my code in yours. So my code as it is might not work directly. Make sure you have correct date_format variable set, it has to be either '%d/%m/%Y' or '%m/%d/%Y'. So instead of doing what I do just pass one of these based on your report condition and see if it works.

Comment: Check my updated gist and see if that works: https://gist.github.com/maulik13/088c022c9a25fd36a218 I modified the view.

Comment: ,i tried your code,form is not getting posted,issue is if i click next button it should save and redirect to next page,it is stay in same page.

Comment: Are you getting validation error when you submit the form? Are you printing these errors in your page?

Comment: If your submitted form goes into if `request.method == "POST"` condition the only thing between redirect and this condition is `is_valid()` method. What happens if you insert an `assert False` in the if condition?

Comment: ,i tried it by putting assert False in request.POST,i got this error "AssertionError at /member/when/
No exception supplied"

Comment: That means your code is reaching the POST condition. How about if you move the assert inside `if form.is_valid()` condition and see if you get assertion error.

Comment: The goal with putting these assertions is to try to figure out why your data is not saved correctly and redirected to the correct page.

Comment: so no data is posted from form to save,even the instance are avail in form field

Comment: It seems your form is posted. It will not save only if it is not validated. Could we move to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32455/discussion-between-user2086641-and-maulik13)

Answer (score 5):

Simplest solution is create factory for presenting form:

```
def ReportFormFactory(date_format):
    class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
       manual_date = forms.DateField(
          input_formats=[date_format],
          widget=forms.DateInput(format=date_format)
       )
    return ReturnForm
```

and then in view:

```
if int(dateformat):
    ReportForm = ReportFormFactory('%m/%d/%Y')
else:
    ReportForm = ReportFormFactory('%d/%m/%Y')
```

dates should be changed to strings only at presention stage in widget, in other places left them as datetime or date objects

Comment: ,I am getting this error "Exception Type: NameError at /member/when/
Exception Value: global name 'ReportDatetimeForm' is not defined"

Comment: Where you have ReportDatetimeForm ?!

Comment: Sorry dswistowski,i did that mistake and cleared that,now what i need is,the entered date should not clear after form post.For this,i had added the instance of the model,even then the data gets disappeared after form post.

Comment: can you tell me hoe to show the posted date after form post,that is,the field should be in update mode.

Comment: ,can you tell me how to show the date in updated mode using your approach.

Comment: form = ReportFormFactory(dateformat)(request.POST, instance=instance), date in view will be rendered by the widged with selected dateformat

Comment: I replaced reportform=ReportForm(request.POST,instance=report)with form = ReportFormFactory(dateformat)(request.POST, instance=instance) still not able to see the added data in widgets,the form is not holding the instance after post.can you give document related to this for refer or provide me how to do this.

Comment: TheForm = ReportFormFactory('%m/%d/%Y') 
instance = Report(manual_date=date.today() - timedelta(7), user=user)
form = TheForm({'manual_date': '2/15/2013', 'user': user.id}, instance=instance)
t = Template('{{ form.manual_date }}')
print t.render(Context({'form': form}))
<input type="text" name="manual_date" value="2/15/2013" id="id_manual_date" />
form.is_valid()
print form.cleaned_data['manual_date'].__class__, form.cleaned_data['manual_date']
<type 'datetime.date'> 2013-02-15

Comment: See,every thing is ok,now just i want to show the date in updated mode,please guide me how to do using formFactory.

Comment: After update and save it's in Report object, so you can change date in any format using strftime method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32260/discussion-between-user2086641-and-dswistowski)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to inherit `DateField` and override `strptime` method to do what you want.

```
class MyDateField(forms.DateField):
    def strptime(self, value, format):
        # Ignore format and continue by your dateformat
        if int(dateformat):
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(force_str(value), '%m/%d/%Y').date()
        else:
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(force_str(value), '%d/%m/%Y').date()
        # Output for debugging
        print "Raw input: '%s', dateformat: %s, date: %s" % (value, dateformat, date)
        return date

class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    manual_date = MyDateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y',
        attrs='size':'15', 'id':'datepicker', 'readonly':'readonly'}))
```

I do not know where the `dateformat` flag comes from, so it may cause some troubles.

Note: *I just noticed that the widget is read-only. Why do you want to add it into the form? It would be much simpler if you just show the date in the template.*

Note2: *There is several things you should be aware of: You have* `d/m/Y` *format set in your widget and in datepicker, these are likely to cause troubles. You should pass date instances as initial values in your form, that should work better.*

Comment: dateformat flag comes from dateformat table,if value is 1 the input format should be mm/dd/yyyy and 0 for dd/mm/yyyy format.I tried your answer sorry to say still the problem is their.

Comment: Here i am explaining the problem so that will easy to find what i am doing wrong.While giving input in (dd/mm/yyyy) format no problem but in (mm/dd/yyyy) format,in database format gets interchange and save. /eg.If the input is (05/07/2013 in format mm/dd/yyyy) in database it save as (07/05/2013)date and month gets interchange.So kindly tell me how to save both input format in this only format(dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: This solution works on a small example I tried. In my case I could save both mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy formats in database reliably. The key is your dateformat should match in MyDateField and your view. Have you tried to strip your code down to focus on the date?

Comment: Maulik,i also now tried,after using this in form,for mm/dd/yyyy it is working fine but for dd/mm/yyyy the same problem is happening.Can you please tell me how to save both format in database in one format.Because while saving date of 02/05/2013 get swap the date and month and save in database.If this is not happening definitely my problem will be solve.I am searching for that but with no success,please provide your answer for save both format in database as yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: See my answer on how to debug this.

Comment: @user2086641: Have you checked what is stored in database directly? I believe your problem is the conversion from POST data to python date object, everything else should work just fine.

Comment: @ziima, think the problem is that,so better to prevent this problem what i thought was to write a custom save function in form,so before save the date object i have to convert it to this format yyyy-mm-dd and save it in database

Comment: Let`s try to add the `print` I`ve put in my example and tell us whether it works or not. Also please show `Report` model and code for `dateformat` variable.

Comment: @user2086641 You should try to avoid doing this in save. The fundamental issue is of conversion from string data to python object. And this is done in the form field definition.

Comment: @ziima,i tried your updated code without giving input_formats,for this case dd/mm/yyyy,if the given date is like this 20/06/2013 it is throwing validation error and if i enter 1/06/2013 after form post it is taking as jan 6,but it is june 1st according to my view.If i pass the input_formats in forms.py the same problem is happen for mm/dd/yyyy format

Comment: @ziima,models.py and dateformat variable views.py are updated in question

Comment: @user2086641 Do you change the `dateformat` during the test? If so, does the output of the print changes? It is possible that the `dateformat` variable gets initialized on module load and then does not change.

Comment: Ist i checked without changing the date format later i changed dateformat and checked,but i don't see any thing printed in console

Comment: @user2086641 Create Gist or similar snippet and post the link here.

Comment: @maulik13,i commented my form and tried Ziima's entire thing in forms.py,the change is already in my code issue with mm/dd/yyyy format and after applying ziima's code it is changed to dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: @user2086641 I don't see that in your gist.

Comment: @maulik13,i had not included in gist,since the same problem was their,i created gist with my old code.

Comment: Your old code definitely would not work. Since that does not deal with the format changes. Could you try with ziima's code and post that?

Comment: I checked Ziima's code and tried,i commented this line "date = report.manual_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')" in views.py and tested,so how it is working means if i enter 12/02/2013 in mm/dd/yyyy format,it is showing as 2nd dec and and if i select dd/mm/yyyy format and enter 12/02/2013 it is showing as 2nd dec,format selection is not accepted what ever i enter it is taking as in dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: @maulik13,any update on this to solve this,depend on my last reply.

Comment: Could you post a new gist with ziima's code, the last one you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the old date formatting problem. Have you considered storing all your dates in a [timestamp format[([Are unix timestamps the best way to store timestamps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178704/are-unix-timestamps-the-best-way-to-store-timestamps)) and then formatting them correctly when displaying/saving.

I suggest you always display the date in a certain format, and make sure the date comes back from the view in the same format. For an input form, giving variety isn't worth the hassle.

Comment: This is a Django application - dates are stored in database utilizing Django DateField class which handles conversion to/from string. There is no need to deal with this problem manually - Django should just be configured properly as stated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you should rely on Django > 1.2 capability to localize date format. Django handles outputting date in localized format as well as handling form submits with localized dates out of the box. You just need to give the user capability to set his/her desired locale and Django would handle different formats by itself.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/formatting/

Answer (score 0):

Try does your code is more clearly:

```
reportform = ReportForm(request.POST or None,
                        instance=report,
                        initial={'manual_date':date, 'manual_time':time})
if reportform.is_valid():
    report = reportform.save(commit=False)
    report.user = request.user
    report.save()
```

What format sent your client after save form?