# Python - Django project - DateTimeField format

Tags: python, django

I want to change the format of the Date in my Django project.

Now it looks like this: "June 3, 2018, 2:19 p.m.", and I want something like: "23,Oct 2018 - 18H23m".

The model that I have its setting this time:

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How can I format the date to the way I want? Are there any other parameters that allow me to do this?

I have just started working with django 2 days ago.

I tried to search around but didnt find any answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date format python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541640/convert-date-format-python)

Answer (score 1):

[`strftime()`](http://strftime.org/) allows you to format datetimes as you like for printing etc:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.today()
print(today.strftime("%d, %b %Y - %HH%Mm"))
>>> 03, Jun 2018 - 16H54m
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these following formats with `strftime()` that returns a string representing the date, controlled by an explicit format string of python. For a complete list of formatting directives: see [this section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

>>> date.strftime("%d %b, %Y - %Ih%Mm%S %p") # With AM PM
>>> '03 Jun, 2018 - 12h02m49s PM'

>>> date.strftime("%d %b, %Y - %Hh%Mm")
>>> '03 Jun, 2018 - 12h04m'
```

You can use `DATETIME_FORMAT = "d M Y H:i:s"` in your settings to change the display format.

Comment: Thank a lot!! 

i used the DATETIME_FORMAT in setting like this "DATETIME_FORMAT = "d, M Y - H:i"

thank you all for the help ;)