# How to fix date formatting using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I have data with the date format as follows:

```py
    date_format = 190410
    year  = 19
    month = 04
    date  = 10
```

I want to change the date format, to be like this:

```
date_format = 10-04-2019
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date format python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541640/convert-date-format-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date = 190410
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date), "%y%m%d").strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
'10-04-2019'
```

`datetime.strptime()` takes a data string and a format, and turns that into `datetime` object, and `datetime` objects have a method called `strftime` that turns `datetime` objects to string with given format. You can look what `%y %m %d %Y` are from [here](http://strftime.org/).

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want(Notice that you have to change your format)

```py
import datetime

date_format = '2019-04-10'

date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_format, '%Y-%m-%d')

print(date_time_obj)
```

Here is an other example

```py
import datetime

date_time_str = '2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860'  
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

print('Date:', date_time_obj.date())  
print('Time:', date_time_obj.time())  
print('Date-time:', date_time_obj)
```

You can also do this

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
s = "20120213"
# you could also import date instead of datetime and use that.
date = datetime(year=int(s[0:4]), month=int(s[4:6]), day=int(s[6:8]))

print(date)
```

There are many ways to achieve what you want.