# Formatting dates in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a date in this format:

```
"2015/05/25"
```

How to format it like this:

```
"2015-05-25"
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Even a trivial character replacement would suffice here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date format python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541640/convert-date-format-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use built-in replace method for completing this task.

```
dateStr = "2015/05/25"
dateStr = dateStr.replace("/","-")
print(dateStr)
```

For more information about the replace function, you can read 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/

Comment: Would recommend using `datetime` module if you plan to actually use these dates